# iPhone constantly dropping connection via USB to my MacBook Pro

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, usb

I have a MB Pro Mid 2015 (15'') and an iPhone SE 128GB and every now and then when I connect the phone to the laptop it drops the connection after few seconds, then connects again, drops etc... Resetting USB ports or NVRAm seems to do the trick for a while, but it is only a matter of time, before the same thing happens again. Is there any permanent solution to this, or should I just live with it?

I am not completely sure if it the problem is mac or iPhone related. All other peripherals connect without problems (although sometimes a standard usb for example is not recognised right away, so I have to unplug it and plug it back in to work).

Thank you in advance for your help,

cheers

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. I have asked [basically the same question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/339261/45492) a few months ago and even offered a bounty. It is some weird bug in macOS, iOS, or both it seems.