# Macbook Pro 15 Late 2015 USB rapidly disconnecting

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, usb, charging

I just got a macbook pro 15' late 2015 from my work. I have an issue where my ipad and iphone cant be charge or connected to the macbook, it keeps disconnecting and it charge for one second and then disconnect and keep doing that.

I tried to run `sudo killall -STOP usbd` , the transfer/connection with my ipad works but it wont charge. I know most people will say 'dont charge your ipad with your mac because it wont work or slow', but I got my own macbook pro 13' late 2015 and i got no issue at all to charge my ipad and share screen using my ipad

I am just wondering if there is an issue with the hardware of my macbook or is there something else ?

p/s : In the system info, it says 'extra operating current : 0 '

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/351922/313842 <- "Force Quit" `usbd` from Activity Monitor. Please see "Linked" questions in the sidebar of that post too.